# Que tal criarmos um post para referência?

Tags: debate

Seria possível fazer feito um *Reference?*  Igual aos do Stack Overflow: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php),[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php),[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Imagino eu, que fosse um wiki comunitário mostrando materiais para aprender, nem que seja o básico, pois muitas perguntas aparecem querendo saber como "*dar o pontapé inicial em X linguagem*".

Talvez se colocasse como wiki comunitário, eliminasse o problema de baseado em opiniões.

Outra alternativa seria trazer o conteúdo das Tag's mais além, mais visível, uma vez que são poucos que olham detalhadamente as tags(provavelmente para editar e fazer correções/melhorias).

Além disso, criar um wiki para os erros também ajuda bastante, e que ainda seja em português realmente ajudaria muito, principalmente porque quase todo conteúdo é em inglês e encontrar algo em português seria muito legal e produtivo.

<sub>Somente lembrando que reduzir o campo de pesquisa sobre X linguagem realmente ajuda muito, principalmente para quem está iniciando.</sub>

Comment: Estava vendo aqui, parece que começou a temporada de entrega de trabalhos das faculdades. Seria muito útil esse tipo de tópico até para tratar questões [como essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240423/64969) de maneira já unificada. Esperando a sugestão do Maniero para ver como tratar isso da melhor maneira

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu tentei a abordagem, não deu certo:

- Primeiro porque as pessoas não entenderam no começo minha proposta (rolou alguns atritos)
- Segundo porque quase ninguém se interessou (depois).

Minhas tentativas tiveram algum apoio, vi outros tentarem também, mas não necessário para que as pessoas criaram perguntas assim, ainda tem um ou outro que faz, mas é esporadicamente:

- [Upload não funciona $_FILES undefined index error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50988/3635)
- [Erro $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50981/3635)
- [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635)
- [Script retornando Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51002/3635)
- [Qual diferença do Xampp, Wamp, EasyPHP, Zwamp e PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115689/3635)

As sobre `$_FILES` e sobre `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` ganharam downvotes imediatos, e não foi um só, claro que muitos foram removidos, mas garanto que eu tive que bater boca. Eu citei os exemplos acima sobre porque foi aonde tentei a abordagem com alguma força a mais, mas também tentei o mesmo em outras linguagens/situações.

Vou ser sincero, somos como comunidade bons em:

- ajudar
- responder
- detalhar
- organizar

Eu arrisco dizer que devemos ser a comunidade **top 10** da rede **SE** que melhor organiza as coisas, mas devo ser sincero, mesmo no melhor dos cenários **não** somos tão bons de *maneira comunitária*, aqui cada um atua de maneira um tanto quanto *solo* e o máximo de apoio são upvotes.

O único lugar que eu vejo funcionar um pouco melhor o espirito comunitário *à lá viva o Wiki* é no **Meta** e olha que nem é tão bom assim, dá pra dizer que é no máximo mediano.

Desculpe se pareci que perdi o foco, a ideia é explicar que não temos maturidade talvez para atuar assim, mas ainda sim eu tenho uma sugestão que do meu ponto de vista pode ser um bom caminho, leia abaixo.

---

### Sobre a sua ideia

Eu acho a ideia legal parcialmente, mas penso que usar o Wiki de Tag seja mais interessante, o que falta pro wiki de tag melhorar é um "UI" com um "UX" melhor.

A minha ideia é que as tags tivessem um certo destaque dentro dos sites da rede, talvez algo como mostrando o começo do Wiki em todas perguntas aonde aquela for a **tag principal** semelhante ao que o [***Google buscador faz***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci7Tt.png), ficaria algo semelhante (sugestão apenas):

> [image: WIKI]

E o segundo passo seria as pessoas que tem experiencia no site se esforçassem um pouco ao menos para indicar para os claramente iniciantes o link `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[TAG]` com alguma explicação.

Isto tudo é sugestão apenas.

Comment: Gostei das suas sugestões, agora basta aguardar os comentários de outros. Muito interessante a sua maneira de trazer o wiki de tag mais perto das perguntas.

Answer (score 2):

Já foi discutido que na forma geral não é adequado ao site. Mas eu estou bolando uma forma de ter este conteúdo no site de uma forma que fique bom para todo mundo.

CW resolve um problema, não o baseado em opiniões.

Aceitar perguntas do tipo acho que não acontecerá, ter o conteúdo poderá acontecer se a comunidade gostar da minha proposta quando eu tiver tempo para finalizar.

Existe site 100% correto e superior.